# Laravel Elixir - Gulp watch not finishing until terminal gets focus

Tags: laravel, gulp, focus, watch, laravel-elixir

I am using Laravel Elix and Gulp (on Windows 8) to combine and compile my `Angular.js` and `SCSS` files. Se the code bellow:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('./tasks/angular.task.js');
require('./tasks/bower.task.js');
require('laravel-elixir-livereload');

elixir.config.js.outputFolder = 'public/js/';

elixir(function(mix){
     mix
        .sass('app.scss')
        .bower()
        .angular('resources/assets/angular/');
});
```

The problem is that when I am running `gulp watch` the combined `all.js` file will not update until i click the terminal window (give it focus). It's showing that the gulp has finished the task:

```
[13:26:45] Finished 'angular in resources/assets/angular/' after 26 ms
```

Comment: Are you sure that's when it finishes, or just when the terminal window gets updated? Because the time taken to process it (26ms) looks good. Are you using the default `cmd`, or some other alternative such as cmder, Console2, etc?

Comment: I have tried to wait 30-40 seconds as well, but the `all.js` only updates right after i click the terminal window. I am using the standard windows `cmd`.

Comment: By "update" you mean write the file to disk or update the file in your browser? (as I see you're using LiveReload).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on that, I mean write the file to disk. It "feels" like it stays in memory until i click on the terminal window. I will delete all my node modules now and try a fresh install and see if that helps. I will post the results here.

Comment: Ok. So I have done some further testing and it seems that it does really write the file to disk. It is only my IDE (PhpStorm) that does not update its representation of the file until I blur the IDE and then focus back on it (hence the reason i thought the focus on the terminal was updating the file). This question seems pointless now, should I maybe remove it?

Comment: The question seems valid enough as some other users might run into this and not understand it. Some IDEs auto refresh open files automatically and some don't. Just update it to include the relevant details about the fact that you're using PhpStorm and move the comment explaining the solution to an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading previous comments, I think there's still a solution that's available to use, if willing:

Going to System Settings under the Synchronization section you can set the file save on a timer when application is idle.

That way you'll have the watcher run as expected while you're typing.

[image: System Settings]